# Linker command failed with exit code 1 Scott

Tags: c++

I realize that my previous question was not worded specifically enough, so i will attempt again. I have been seeing similar problems where i do not have the proper .m files added to my compile sources, is it possible that that is the case? The following is my code

```
//: CO2:Hello.cpp
// Saying Hello with C++
#include <iostream> // Stream declarations
using namespace std;

int main()    {
cout << "Hello, World! I am "
<< 8 << " Today!" << endl;
} ///:~
```

And this is the detailed error message that i have been receiving

Ld /Users/scotglener/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/COM206-btdjjopfjlpsuygxgdjnxemfqgbb/Build/Products/Debug/COM206 normal x86_64
    cd /Users/scotglener/Desktop/COM206
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.10
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk -L/Users/scotglener/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/COM206-btdjjopfjlpsuygxgdjnxemfqgbb/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/scotglener/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/COM206-btdjjopfjlpsuygxgdjnxemfqgbb/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/scotglener/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/COM206-btdjjopfjlpsuygxgdjnxemfqgbb/Build/Intermediates/COM206.build/Debug/COM206.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/COM206.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.10 -stdlib=libc++ -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/scotglener/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/COM206-btdjjopfjlpsuygxgdjnxemfqgbb/Build/Intermediates/COM206.build/Debug/COM206.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/COM206_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/scotglener/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/COM206-btdjjopfjlpsuygxgdjnxemfqgbb/Build/Products/Debug/COM206

duplicate symbol _main in:
    /Users/scotglener/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/COM206-btdjjopfjlpsuygxgdjnxemfqgbb/Build/Intermediates/COM206.build/Debug/COM206.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
    /Users/scotglener/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/COM206-btdjjopfjlpsuygxgdjnxemfqgbb/Build/Intermediates/COM206.build/Debug/COM206.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/HelloWorld.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: You have more than one `main` function in your project. (I think one is in "main.cpp" and one in "HelloWorld.cpp".)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have two files in your project main.cpp and HelloWorld.cpp, both of them define a `main` function. Since it seems that you only want the HelloWorld.cpp version the solution is to delete main.cpp from your project.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you have accidentally added two `.cpp` files with `main` functions into your project. (Most likely their names are `main.cpp` and `HelloWorld.cpp`). There should always be no more than one function with the same signature in the project (It is called One Definition Rule). You have to move each file into its own project.

Comment: You can have the same function name with different arguments, function overloading

Comment: Indeed. Corrected the answer.